# Using inner join to reduce results. Do I need to reference new table anywhere beyond the join statement?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, join

I'm wondering if I can just do an inner join as kind of a where clause by itself. Or if I use a field from the joined table in my where clause, if it's redundant.

```
    select * from T1   inner join T2   on T1.id = T2.id   where T2.z is not null
```

Is the "T2.z is null" part redundant if all I want returned are records in T1 where the same id exists in T2?

Comment: @kateract - `t2.id is null` would not be redundant; it would screen out all rows that could possibly satisfy the inner join condition, so in the end no rows would be returned from the whole query. Perhaps you meant `t2.id is NOT null`?

Comment: yes, meant to type   "where T2.z is not null"

Comment: @mathguy yes, sorry.  What I meant to say was: `T2.id is not Null` would be redundant, but `T2.z is not Null` would filter out rows where there was a `T2.id`, but `T2.z` is `Null`. While that condition doesn't necessarily exist in your database, it would not be redundant.  I deleted my old comment for clarity.

Comment: @bluewater You can always [edit] your question if you need to change something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, `select * from t1 inner join t2 [...]` will not return records in `t1` - it will return all the columns of `t1` **and** `t2`. You could fix that by selecting specifically the columns in `t1` - don't `select *`.

Then, if there are many rows in `t2` with the same `t2.id`, matching a given `t1.id`, you will get a whole bunch of rows in the result for that one row in the input `t1`. So you will not always "reduce" the result set.

It seems what you want can be achieved with the `in` operator, something like

```
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select id from t2);
```

This is equivalent to the following modification of your query. You do **not** need a `where` clause for this to work:

```
select t1.* from t1 inner join (select distinct id from t2) b on t1.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following query,

```
select t1.* from T1   inner join T2   on T1.id = T2.id   where T2.z is NOT null
```

The `WHERE` condition is redundant, assuming that T2.Z is a `NOT NULL` column.

That would leave you with this:

```
select t1.* from T1   inner join T2   on T1.id = T2.id
```

, which is a little odd because, in a normally designed database, either `T1.id` or `T2.id` would be the primary key of its table.

If `T1.id` is the primary key of `T1`, then your query is going to return duplicates -- each `T1` row will be repeated once for each child that exists in `T2`.

If `T2.id` is the primary key of `T2`, then you should not need to join to `T2` at all, because every possible `T1.id` value must exist in `T2.id`, because of the `FOREIGN KEY` relationship that (should) exist.  In that case, you could have written:

```
select t1.* from T1 WHERE T1.id is not null;
```

So, the answer to your question is that you do not need to reference the tables outside of the join condition in order for the join to be applied.  But something seems a little off about the approach.

Comment: Correct observations especially about things being off. Unfortunately I work with tables that don't have defined primary and foreign keys. It's a constant challenge trying to pull the correct data.